# Add dynamic team actions in Eclipse

Tags: eclipse, eclipse-plugin

I am developing an Eclipse Team Plugin. I want to contribute the **Team popup menu**, so I have defined an action in my plugin.xml file:

```
<plugin>
    <extension point="org.eclipse.ui.popupMenus">
        <objectContribution
                adaptable="true"
                id="com.myexample.ui.ResourceContributions"
                objectClass="org.eclipse.core.resources.IResource">
            <action
                class="com.myexample.ui.actions.MyAction"
                id="com.myexample.ui.actions.MyActionId"
                label="Execute action" />
        </objectContribution>
    </extension
</plugin>
```

Also have an implementation for the action:

```
public class MyAction extends TeamAction {
   ...
}
```

At this point all is ok, my action is shown and I can execute it.

Now, what I want is **to change the text of the action dynamically**, when the selection changes, depending in some properties of the selected objects.

Is this possible? How could I do it? Could I do it programmatically?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Here is what I would try:

- Override `TeamAction.selectionChanged(IAction action, ISelection selection)` in your MyAction class
- Invoke `IAction.setText(String text)` in your overridden method.